# How to access the output of a sub-chain or subgraph in a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a simple chain in Mathematica

```
myChain = NetChain[{
  LinearLayer[100],
  myLittleChain[],
  LinearLayer[25],
  SoftmaxLayer[]
}]
```

with a sub-chain

```
myLittleChain[] = NetChain[{LinearLayer[50], Ramp}]
```

I can access the output of say the first linear layer with

```
NetMeasurements[myTrainedChain, someData, NetPort[{1, "Output"}]];
```

But how do I access the output from the linear layer inside the sub-chain.
I want a way which would generalize to netgraphs so I could potentially have several sub-chains in parallel.

Comment: Are you looking to create a network that has multiple outputs in practice?  If so, you will want to use `NetGraph` (instead of `NetChain`) and define multiple output ports.  If instead you're merely looking to extract what the values are from your trained network, something like `subNet= NetTake[myTrainedChain,2]` will extract the part of your network up to the second layer.  You can then feed data into `subNet` and see what the output is.

Comment: It’s the second of these, i.e., to monitor what the network is doing, that I am interested in. I see how your suggestion could be useful in some circumstances, but I am interested in what is going on at a particular layer when I feed real data into the top level. I just can’t see an easy way of referencing a layer in a sub-net in a way that NetPort will accept.